# Is this possible in coding

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `jQuery` i want to compare multiple values in `if()` parenthesis, my requirement is as below.
Currently I am trying this in `jQuery`, let me know if it works in other environment.

```
if((a==b && c==d) || (a!=b && c!=d)){
// code goes here

}
```

**Edit**

This is my scenario;

```
 if (($(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Color").children(":first").val() != "" &&  $(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Size").children(":first").val() != "")  || ($(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Color").children(":first").val() !== undefined &&  $(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Size").children(":first").val() !== undefined ))
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: what other environment ??

Comment: @Mureinik above condition will work or not? because it is not working here with my code

Comment: Looks OK. Perhaps you could provide a fuller snippet and explain what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Vicmathur I am running this in jQuery, will it work in C#, PHP, Java etc

Comment: if you are going to run that syntax in javascript, then that would probably work

Comment: there ısnt problem on this

Comment: **will it work in C#, PHP, Java etc**  if you cannot answer this yourself then you have a long way to go..

Comment: why not use required attribute??

Comment: @Mureinik kindly check edit

Comment: @madalinivascu how?

Comment: `<input type="text" required>`

Comment: @madalinivascu but these values are dynamically showing in @Html.DropDownList(), how to place required attribute there

Comment: read the documentation, i am not familiar with that language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you are trying to check if the product color and size input have value..

```
//Declare variable here for ease of maintenance and to avoid repetitive calls on the same node...
var productAttrInputColor = $(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Color").children(":first").val(),
    productAttrInputSize = $(".product_attribute_input" + id + "_Size").children(":first").val();

if (productAttrInputColor || productAttrInputSize) {
    //Do something if the above condition returns a truthy values
}
```

Also, notice that I removed the conditional operator for checking `empty string`, `undefined`. Since the above conditional statement will translate the value into Boolean true, and thus execute the code block.

Answer (score 3):

You want an inverted xor operation. This can be shortened to:

```
if((a==b) == (c==d)){
// code goes here

}
```